# Limit MySQL search output to 10

Tags: php, html, navigation

I am trying to create a social network. In the profile details I want to display at least 10 friends of that profile user. I used:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("...","...","...","dbname"); //NOT REALLY IMPORTANT
$find = "SELECT * FROM friendslist WHERE user1 = '$myusername'";
$exec = mysqli_query($connect,$find);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec)) {
$friendusername = $row['user2'];

$con2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$friendusername' ";
$exec2 = mysqli_query($con,$con2);
$row2 = myslqi_fetch_assoc($exec2);

echo $row2['firstname']."<br/>";
```

My tables:

```
FOR friends:
id, user1, user2

FOR users
id, username, firstname
```

It will display all my friends like if I have 20 friends, it will display all 20 of them. How can I limit it to display only 10?

Comment: It's basic SQL - `LIMIT`. Why didn't you google it?

Comment: @pc-shooter And yet you answered... with a typo due to your haste :p

Comment: It just displayed LIMIT to searches. Where will I put LIMIT for output?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I deleted it. Didn't see... everyone makes mistakes sometimes. Important is to correct them isn't it?

Comment: @RunCode common... https://www.google.ch/search?q=mysql+limit+rsults&oq=mysql+limit+rsults&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5638j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8#q=mysql+limit+results&safe=off&spell=1

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol BTW If I look at some of your answers.... they shouldn't be there neither...

Comment: @pc-shooter Yeah I know how to LIMIT the 'SQL Search'. What I needed was how to LIMIT the "while" code there so that it will only display 10 results not the whole 20. Please kindly read the question again. Thank you.

Comment: @RunCode add "LIMIT 10" to your SQL query.  That's how you cap the output to 10 rows. YOur goal is to construct queries that are optimized for their intended use; querying all of your rows to only output 10 is terribly inefficient.

Comment: add acounter in the loop, count to ten, break..... again,common

Comment: @pc-shooter Hehe, you got me, but I'm trying to improve ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$find = "SELECT * FROM friendslist WHERE user1 = '$myusername' LIMIT 0, 10";
```

Comment: `LIMT`... nice typo :p

Answer (score 0):

Like @Danijel's answers, good option is join the tables.

First join tables,  get friendlist with **f.user1 = '$myusername'** and later limit it to ten.

PD: Don't do queries in a loop, it's bad for perfomance

```
$find = "SELECT * 
         FROM friendslist  f, users u
         WHERE     f.user2 = u.username 
               AND f.user1 = '$myusername' 
         LIMIT 10";

        $exec = mysqli_query($connect,$find);

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec)) {

              echo $row2['firstname']."<br/>";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks man. It will limit the 'find' command to display only 1 user. What I needed was how to LIMIT the `while(....)` code that after it displays 10, it will stop displaying more users. Thanks! Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Join the queries and limit to 10.

```
"SELECT * FROM friendslist LEFT JOIN users ON friendslist.user2=users.username WHERE user1 = '$myusername' LIMIT 10"
```